# Wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) - Rails - Maybe Strong Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I am receiving the error 'wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)' when attempting a tutorial online. I am completely new to Rails and just trying to follow through the guide.

My controller is:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

def new

end

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
end

private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

end
```

My database code is:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
     t.string :title
     t.text :text

     t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The parameters given are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JfpQBSnxU8O839o5YjbZV11TMAWTPgaok1/skSEoGlchdGCulmJuGxFdyj7lUK6WIfrLddCZAaWxOkxRaNqlTA==",
"article"=>{"title"=>"hello world",
"text"=>"hello olivia"},
"commit"=>"Save Article"}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: hey, can you show the error you're receiving please.

Comment: Hey yes it's 

    ArgumentError in ArticlesController#create

Comment: Stack trace of error please?

Comment: Uploaded screenshot to here: http://imgur.com/Unpub9a

Please let me know if that's not what you meant.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether the article being created? try this:

    `if @article.save
       redirect_to article_path(@article)
    end`

Comment: The log messages in the image suggest that this is rather an issue with the `redirect_to` line in the article controller. Does the error change when you use `redirect_to article_url(@article)` instead?

Comment: @toddmetheny Neither of those seemed to make any different within the log messages. It is still redirecting to a 500 internal server error.

Comment: It may be a method on the actual page you're redirecting to.

Comment: @OEThorne Did you even solve this? Getting stuck with this too. The problem is with the  `.new(params)` call.

Answer (score 0):

If you try this code, will it print any error in the console?

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
     def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      end

    def new

    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        if @article.save
          redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
           logger.warn(@article.errors)
          render "new"
        end
    end

    private
        def article_params
          params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
        end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because you're not calling @article.save in an if block. You're calling @article.save and then calling a redirect. Trying using:

```
if @article.save
  redirect_to @article
else
  render :new
end
```

Comment: Tried this but still getting the same internal server error.

Comment: Also, try adding @article = Article.new to your new method.